# vim-airline blocky in console

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

I installed vim-airline (MacBook Pro running Yosemite) to use in Terminal.app (zsh + tmux). Here is how it looks, along with the relevant lines of my vimrc. I'm using Inconsolata-g-powerline. Any ideas on how to fix?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You should use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: When you say “I’m using Inconsolata-g-powerline”, is that font specified in your vimrc or in Terminal? I think it has to be specified in Terminal, e.g. selected in in Preferences > Settings > Profiles > [your profile] > Text > Font.

Comment: It's selected in Terminal, I don't think the vimrc option for font applies to the console mode.

Comment: I had trouble with vim-airline, so I switched to powerline, which is awesome because it works with vim, bash, zsh, and tmux. https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/